# jQuery keyup event not executing immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I have following small jQuery script:

```
      $("#content").on("keyup", "#ID1", function() {
        $("#ID2").load("loadText", resizeResult());
      });

      function resizeResult() {
        if($("#ID2").height() != $("#ID3").height()){
          $("#ID3").animate({
            height: $("#ID2").height()
          }, 800);
        }
      }
```

My problem now is that the resize function will be only executed by the **NEXT "keyup"** event but I want it **immediately** when the **"load" in ID2** is done.

Answer (score 0):

Call resizeResult() in the end of keyupfunction

```
$("#content").on("keyup", "#ID1", function() {
       ..................

       resizeResult();
      });
```

Comment: no improvement. guess the problem is the dynamic content of the load. actually i dont use a string, but a http request to get the content for the div. maybe there is a delay between updating the dom and calculating the size of the div.

Answer (score 0):

call your load function in document.ready too..

```
$(function(){
   $("#ID2").load("loadText", resizeResult());  //<-- call load function in document ready and in keyup function..
   $("#content").on("keyup", "#ID1", function() {
      $("#ID2").load("loadText", resizeResult());
   })
   .....
});
```

and please make sure your url in load is proper path... loadText doesnot seems to be a proper path

Comment: ok i´ll test it. normally this code from groovy will be load:
load("${createLink(action: 'searchDeliveryaddress')}?q="

Comment: ok... try it out... if the url is correct this should work.. let me know

Comment: Approvement achieved: On the first keyup events (results for the search are delivered with the second letter) the resize works. When i remove one letter, the results disappear, but resize is stuck again. Gets updated on the next keyup event. I can't use the load on document ready, because i have two different functions loading into the same div, depending on the form field used. So fpr now i have just added $(document).ready(resizeResult());

Comment: ok i´ve solved it for now. the problem was the browser-renderer which not known the new height from the div. so i set a `setTimeout(function () {...}` before the height will be animate. 
thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks well in your code. But you need to leave the brackets from the `resizeResult` function inside the event. Because you don´t want it to call immediately when the browser executes the script. It´s only needed when the event is fired. So you should change your code to this (and my also native common events, which recommend jQuery):

```
$("#content").keyup(function() {
   $("#ID2").load("loadText", resizeResult);
});

function resizeResult() {
   if($("#ID2").height() != $("#ID3").height()){
      $("#ID3").animate({
         height: $("#ID2").height()
      }, 800);
   }
}
```

For a safe execution it´s also better to wait until the html is fully loaded or until this html tags are loaded (javascript code after the `ID3` container). The first method can be done by using `$.document.ready` from jQuery.